# Can't figure out how to send a signed POST request to OKEx

Tags: api, rust

I want to send a signed POST request to Okex: [Authentication Docs](https://www.okex.com/docs/en/#summary-yan-zheng) [POST Request Docs](https://www.okex.com/docs/en/#spot-orders).

I always get back an "invalid sign" error.

I successfully sent a signed GET request. For the POST you also need to add the body in the signature. If I do that, none of my signatures are valid anymore. I already verified that my signature is the same as one produced by their official Python SDK (that's why I wrote the JSON by hand. Python has spaces in the JSON). I am new to Rust so I am hoping I am missing something obvious.

OKEx client implementations in other languages: https://github.com/okcoin-okex/open-api-v3-sdk

```rust
/// [dependencies]
/// hmac="0.7.1"
/// reqwest = "0.9.18"
/// chrono = "0.4.6"
/// base64="0.10.1"
/// sha2="0.8.0"

use reqwest::header::{HeaderMap, HeaderValue, CONTENT_TYPE};
use chrono::prelude::{Utc, SecondsFormat};
use hmac::{Hmac, Mac};
use sha2::{Sha256};

static API_KEY: &'static str = "<insert your key!>";
static API_SECRET: &'static str = "<insert your secret!>";
static PASSPHRASE: &'static str = "<insert your passphrase!>";

fn main() {
    let timestamp = Utc::now().to_rfc3339_opts(SecondsFormat::Millis, true);
    let method = "POST";
    let request_path = "/api/spot/v3/orders";

    let body_str = "{\"type\": \"market\", \"side\": \"sell\", \"instrument_id\": \"ETH-USDT\", \"size\": \"0.001\"}";
    let mut signature_content = String::new();
    signature_content.push_str(&timestamp);
    signature_content.push_str(method);
    signature_content.push_str(request_path);
    signature_content.push_str(&body_str);

    type HmacSha256 = Hmac<Sha256>;
    let mut mac = HmacSha256::new_varkey(API_SECRET.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    mac.input(signature_content.as_bytes());
    let signature = mac.result().code();
    let base64_signature = base64::encode(&signature);

    let mut header_map = HeaderMap::new();
    header_map.insert("OK-ACCESS-KEY", HeaderValue::from_str(API_KEY).unwrap());
    header_map.insert("OK-ACCESS-SIGN", HeaderValue::from_str(&base64_signature).unwrap());
    header_map.insert("OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", HeaderValue::from_str(&timestamp).unwrap());
    header_map.insert("OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE", HeaderValue::from_str(PASSPHRASE).unwrap());
    header_map.insert(CONTENT_TYPE, HeaderValue::from_static("application/json; charset=UTF-8"));

    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    let mut complete_url = String::from("https://okex.com");
    complete_url.push_str(request_path);

    let res = client
        .post(complete_url.as_str())
        .headers(header_map)
        .body(body_str)
        .send().unwrap().text();

    println!("{:#?}", res);
}
```

This returns an "Invalid Sign" error at the moment but should return a successful http code (if enough funds are on the account).

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster Added a MRE.

Comment: [To make Stack Overflow a useful resource for future visitors beyond the context of your repository](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/155423), please [edit] your question to add a [MRE] in the question itself, in addition to the link to your repository.

Comment: @Shepmaster Added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use `"https://www.okex.com"` instead of `"https://okex.com`. The latter produces the "Invalid Sign" error. But just for POST requests. Issue was therefore not Rust related.