# How to sign an OKEx POST API request?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, sign

The below is a result of this question [How to sign an OKEx API request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486374/how-to-sign-an-okex-api-request) and some of the answers:

```
import hmac
import base64
import requests
import datetime
import json

from config import KEY, SECRET, PASS, ROOT_URL


def get_time():
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    t = now.isoformat("T", "milliseconds")
    return t + "Z"


def signature(timestamp, request_type, endpoint, body, secret):
    if body != '':
        body = json.dumps(body)
    message = str(timestamp) + str.upper(request_type) + endpoint + body
    print(message)
    mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret, encoding='utf-8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
    d = mac.digest()
    return base64.b64encode(d)


def get_header(request_type, endpoint, body):
    time = get_time()
    header = dict()
    header['CONTENT-TYPE'] = 'application/json'
    header['OK-ACCESS-KEY'] = KEY
    header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = signature(time, request_type, endpoint, body, SECRET)
    header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = str(time)
    header['OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = PASS
    return header


def get(endpoint, body=''):
    url = ROOT_URL + endpoint
    header = get_header('GET', endpoint, body)
    return requests.get(url, headers=header)


def post(endpoint, body=''):
    url = ROOT_URL + endpoint
    header = get_header('POST', endpoint, body)
    return requests.post(url, headers=header)
```

where `KEY, SECRET, PASS` are the API key, secret key, and pass phrase respectively;  The `ROOT_URL` is `'https://www.okex.com'`.

**The Problem**

GET requests work absolutely fine, so when I run the following, there are no issues:

```
ENDPOINT = '/api/v5/account/balance'
BODY = ''

response = get(ENDPOINT)
response.json()
```

However, when I try to place an order via a POST request, like so:

```
ENDPOINT = '/api/v5/trade/order'
BODY = {"instId":"BTC-USDT",
        "tdMode":"cash",
        "side":"buy",
        "ordType":"market",
        "sz":"1"}

response = post(ENDPOINT, body=BODY)
response.json()
```

I get the following output, i.e. it won't accept the signature:

```
{'msg': 'Invalid Sign', 'code': '50113'}
```

**Related Questions**

In this one [Can't figure out how to send a signed POST request to OKEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501032/cant-figure-out-how-to-send-a-signed-post-request-to-okex) an answer was provided, but it does not work for me as I was already using the suggested URL. More or less the same question was asked here [Unable to send a post requests OKEX Invalid Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70267487/unable-to-send-a-post-requests-okex-invalid-signature), but no activity likely due to the format, so I thought I would repost and elaborate.

**OKEX Docs**

The docs simply specify that `The API endpoints of Trade require authentication` (https://www.okex.com/docs-v5/en/?python#rest-api-authentication-signature). But they make no reference to there being any difference between the two methods. Away from that, I am including all required parameters in the body of the post request as far as I can see.

I would appreciate any input on this.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same POST problem and figured it out. I used new domain name okex.com. Here is my code.

```
def set_userinfo(self):
    position_path = "/api/v5/account/set-position-mode"
    try:
        self.get_header("POST", position_path, {"posMode":"net_mode"})
        resp = requests.post(url=self.base_url+position_path, headers=self.headers, json={"posMode":"long_short_mode"}).json()
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("OK set_userinfo error={} type={}".format(f'{e}', f'{type(e)}'))

def get_header(self, request_type, endpoint, body=''):
    timestamp = self.get_time()
    self.headers["OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP"] = timestamp
    self.headers["OK-ACCESS-SIGN"] = self.signature(timestamp, request_type, endpoint, body)

def signature(self, timestamp, request_type, endpoint, body):
    if body != '':
        body = json.dumps(body)
    message = str(timestamp) + str.upper(request_type) + endpoint + body
    mac = hmac.new(bytes(self.secret_key, encoding='utf-8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256').digest()
    return base64.b64encode(mac)
```

Comment: Thanks the other guy who fixed grammar errors in my text.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix the same problem.
Both of the 'body' in signature() and in get_header() should be json.
So you should add following code:

```
if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
    body = ''
else:
    body = json.dumps(body)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and solved it using below code snippet, the idea is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68115787/20497127, but I modified a little by adding POST functionality

```
APIKEY = "" # input key
APISECRET = "" #input secret
PASS = "" #input passphrase


BASE_URL = 'https://www.okx.com'

def send_signed_request(http_method, url_path, payload={}):
    def get_time():
        return dt.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3]+'Z'
    
    def signature(timestamp, method, request_path, body, secret_key):
        if str(body) == '{}' or str(body) == 'None':
            body = ''
        message = str(timestamp) + str.upper(method) + request_path + str(body)
        mac = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, encoding='utf8'), bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), digestmod='sha256')
        d = mac.digest()
        return base64.b64encode(d)
    
    # set request header
    def get_header(request='GET', endpoint='', body:dict=dict()):
        cur_time = get_time()
        header = dict()
        header['CONTENT-TYPE'] = 'application/json'
        header['OK-ACCESS-KEY'] = APIKEY
        header['OK-ACCESS-SIGN'] = signature(cur_time, request, endpoint , body, APISECRET)
        header['OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'] = str(cur_time)
        header['OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'] = PASS
        # demo trading: need to set x-simulated-trading=1, live trading is 0
        header['x-simulated-trading'] = '1'
        return header

    url = BASE_URL + url_path
    header = get_header(http_method, url_path, payload)
    print(url)
    print(header)
    if http_method == 'GET':
        response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
    elif http_method == 'POST':
        response = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=payload)
    return response.json()

# this will run get requests
res = send_signed_request("GET", "/api/v5/account/balance", payload={})

# this will run post requests
data = {
  "instId": "BTC-USDT",
  "tdMode": "cross",
  "side": "sell",
  "ccy":"USDT",
  "ordType": "limit",
  "px": "100000",
  "sz": "0.01"
}

res = send_signed_request("POST", "/api/v5/trade/order", payload=json.dumps(data))
```